# WordPress WC_Meta_Data full variation values

Tags: php, wordpress

I have fairly complex products in my webshop with all kinds of variation values. The length of these values is quite low. The problem is that Wordpress automatically shortens them. So that means that:

Value A: This is a fairly long value chosen for this option

Gets shorten to:

Value A: This is a fairly...is option

I've tried to find the full length values, but can't seem to display them on my Thank You page. It uses this function to show the values:

```
wc_display_item_meta( $item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
```

However, even printing the entire $item output doesn't result in a usable object in which I can find the full-length values. There is the WC_Meta_Data, but it only holds these short values. Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What theme are you using? Using Twenty Nineteen as a test. A long variation completely displays.

[image]

If I had to guess, It maybe something in the theme causing it to shorten it.

Comment: Now I feel silly. I just assumed it was a Woocommerce thing. I will dive into the code of my theme, I'm sure it's in there somewhere. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome and Ive seen some crazy stuff clients put in there over the years and almost always work with a custom theme so never ran into that. It is also possible some plugin is doing it.